# Azure Function App: 'Cold start' happen when debugging locally

Tags: c#, azure, debugging, local, azure-function-app

Lately, I've debugged a Blob Trigger function app in local by Visual Studio 2017.
Now I'm testing with large batch upload for Blob Container (1000 image) and the function app randomly stop listen Blob Container, some time just few minutes, but some time it completely stop listen Blob Container. I guess it is a behavior of Function app called Cold start. 
If I stop debug session and run debug again, It will continue listen Blob Container and function app will be triggered.

Do we have any solution to prevent it or reduce the time of Cold start?

Comment: I don't think when debugging Functions locally the Function ever gets unloaded, thus no Cold Start would happen. Sounds something that should be addressed to the Functions Host team on github https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host

Comment: Please check if the below link helps. https://markheath.net/post/avoiding-azure-functions-cold-starts